# Is it possible not to start a separate io thread in zeromq?

Tags: zeromq

I understand that zeromq will launch new io threads for io operations (epoll, send/recv on sockets), the number of io thread can be controlled in the zmq_context. Zeromq's official document says for any network applications the number of io thread should be at least 1.

My question is that is possible that can I control zeromq not to launch any new io thread, but just use the application thread to do all the epoll/recv/send? I would love to do this because my application is handling very tiny tasks and the cost on thread switch cannot be overlooked.

I have a previous hand-made message layer that does all the stuff in a single thread, but recently I want to switch to a more mature message layer to handle various errors on networks so I am trying to look at whether I can use zeromq.